# Как решить проблему с disk.file.get?

Tags: битрикс, rest, битрикс24

делаю чат-бота и использую disk.file.get, чтобы можно было получить URL фотки, которую прислали, но доступ к этому методу почему-то есть только с того аккаунта, с которого был создан бот, если же зайти с другого аккаунта и также попробовать получить URL фотки, то будет выдавать "Нет прав", хотя url для rest я взял из настроек чат-бота.

Либо альтернативный вопрос, как я могу получить url публичной фотографии через чат-бота? Если в чат-бота я отправлю фотку, то ссылка на фотку, которая пришла на вебхук - будет доступна только тому, кто отправил эту фотку, остальным же будет показываться, что фотка битая